# Rename Azure Storage Table Column

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

As the title says, is it possible to rename an Azure Storage Table column?

I tried using the portal and through storage explorer with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. Haven't had to do this before. But if I had to make a guess, it's that columns don't really exist in table storage. There is no schema anyway, you can include whatever fields in the objects. To rename a column, you'd probably have to go through all the objects and rename the field in them.